# getting error about _bamacgerror in console

Tags: ios, swift

I have some text fields and some button to get data from server.But when my app run and when i touch textfield or button i am getting error like this continuously with up to 20 lines. I am using xcode 7 swift 2.0. Set my deployment as 6.0 above.

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

Help me how to come out from this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be its some bugs about the upgradation of xcode 7.Try to do this. If possible.If it does't work.Let me know.Credits to **Logicsaurus Rex**

[image]

Also see this link it may help you[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899586/error-message-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20)

Hope this help !

Comment: As i said before it may be some bugs about the upgradation . try to google about apple fourms