# _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability(20)/name(15) Error - *IQKeyboardManager*

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error, mach, iqkeyboardmanager

> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
>
> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

This error generates in my all views, when I'm typing through keyboard in a text view, it's not occurring on text fields.

I remove [*`IQKeyboardManager`*](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) and it works fine then. Probably something related to `IQKeyboardManager`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message '\_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899586/error-message-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20)

Comment: no, I checked that link. I tried all the possibilities. it's not working on my case

Comment: ok , but it occur in many scenaiors , how do we find excat solution

Comment: Not sure about that.

Comment: @KiranJasvanee did you find the reason?

Comment: I might have found that time. Now working on swift, since then I haven't went through this errors.