# _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20) & _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Whenever i click on `UIImagePickerController` it gives me this error..i have tried solutions from other links but not able to remove it.can't understand exactly why this error occur ?????

> 2016-04-02 13:27:10.930 project[1984:72176] _BSMachError: (os/kern)
>   invalid capability (20)
>
> 2016-04-02 13:27:10.930 project[1984:72176] _BSMachError: (os/kern)
>   invalid name (15)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message '\_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899586/error-message-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20)

Answer (score 2):

The reason some developers doesn't get the error came back after changing from "Unites States" to "en" (or) other region, is that there is discrepancy between "Property list" and "Source code" views. It's probably Xcode bug. Whenever there is mismatch between these two views will throw this error, whatever it is "en" or "English". But when developer changed to "en" or "United States" will fix that error message.

Based on the https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15683:

Change "Localization native development region" in info.plist to United States instead of en.

Comment: It does work for some folks including me, when deploying from Xcode 7.3.1 to a tethered iPad Air.

Answer (score 0):

One of methods how to resolve that is:

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to: `/Users/YourOSXUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. Delete all folders from "Driver Data"
4. Open Xcode, open project and build again.