# Image Uploading with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I am trying to upload images to server with AFNetworking 3.0.

Here is my code :

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [[manager POST:setUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData)
    {
        //Current date with image name
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:image name:namePara fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]] mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }progress:nil
        success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
            [GMDCircleLoader hideFromView:self.view animated:YES];
            NSMutableDictionary *dir = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:responseObject];
            if([dir valueForKey:@"error"])
            {
                UIAlertController *alert = [[singletone sharedManager]showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"SIGNIN", nil) :[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dir valueForKey:@"error"]] ];
                [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                //Successfull
                UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"REGISTRATION", nil) message:[dir valueForKey:@"success"] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                {
                    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }];
            [alertController addAction:ok];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            NSLog(@"response object : %@",responseObject);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {                        NSLog(@"failure : %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }]resume];
```

It will get in success block with **error : error In Image Uploading.**
 I have also tried from Postman to check my API response, but it's work fine from Postman. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Can you please add a postman screenshot that does the API accepts file as base64 or simple file

Comment: sorry that i can't. but i can tell you the description of the all . that image that i have to send in postman is type of "File". and with other parameters like name,address..etc..  and the response i get is {
  "success": "Delivery registration done successfully"
}

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and it working with AFNetworking 3.0 :

```
 AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];



    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:BaseURL parameters:<parameter dictionary> constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                    {

                                        if (profile_pic.length!=0) {

                                            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"profile_pic" fileName:@"ProfilePic" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                                        }


                                    } error:nil];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
    uploadTask = [manager
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                      // This is not called back on the main queue.
                      // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates

                  }
                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                      if (error)
                      {


                      }
                      else
                      {

                      }
                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: i got response Successful. but at server the image name not found as i send i.e. profilepic

Comment: just confirm your parameter name (name:@"profile_pic") is correct

Comment: ya i conform that parameter. but it strange that with my original parameter it's not working but with your parameter it's working. but not showing the image name at server.

Answer (score 0):

you try this

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Comment: i am trying with  manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]; but it's still not uploding. and also give me the error BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
 _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899586/error-message-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *nsdataFromBase64String = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:imageBytes options:0];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];   

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];// Your API

    [manager POST:stringURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
    {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:nsdataFromBase64String name:fIds fileName:fileN mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    }
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         imgRes=@"success";
         //here is place for code executed in success case
     }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
    {
        imgRes=@"fail";
         //here is place for code executed in error case
     }];
```

Works perfectly at my end

This is what you are using in Postman
[image]

Comment: imageBytes is nsdata?

Comment: Yes, first i get imageBytes from server. And i change it back to NSData to sync the image back to server

Comment: i am getting reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: body

Comment: can you tell me that how to get Image URL if i am select pic from photogellery or camera?

Comment: yes. you r ri8. i am using this way in postman

Comment: i am using send imagedata " NSData *dataToAppend = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.5)" is it the problem ?

Comment: Got this 

Printing description of responseObject:
{
    success = "Delivery registration done successfully";
}

Comment: post your code. by which you get successfull response . i just try

Comment: check for ToyotaSupra for tes1342@test.com

Comment: How come we get success and you cannot see the image on server?

Comment: with the @Ashwini  code pass <formdata> "name" value dummy you will get suceess mesge with no image  but by passing right parameter in name value i.e. "user_photo" you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set requestSerializer to @"multipart/form-data" for @"Content-Type".

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];


    manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [manager POST:setUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:image name:namePara fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]] mimeType:@"image/png"];


    } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

       NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
            [GMDCircleLoader hideFromView:self.view animated:YES];
            NSMutableDictionary *dir = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:responseObject];
            if([dir valueForKey:@"error"])
            {
                UIAlertController *alert = [[singletone sharedManager]showAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"SIGNIN", nil) :[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dir valueForKey:@"error"]] ];
                [self.parentViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                //Successfull
                UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"REGISTRATION", nil) message:[dir valueForKey:@"success"] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                {
                    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }];
            [alertController addAction:ok];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            NSLog(@"response object : %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

    }];
```

Comment: still it's not done. error : "Error in uploading image";

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *nsdataFromBase64String = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:"your image as base64 encoded" options:0];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"wr34", @"delivery_company_name", @"uname", @"user_name", @"123456789", @"contact_info", @"test1342@test.com", @"email",@"123456", @"password",@"SUV", @"car_type",@"White", @"car_color",@"GJ-1AE-2255", @"car_plate_no",@"43345dw", @"car_reg_no",@"123454", @"license_no",@"Model", @"car_model",@"location", @"location",@"4.3", @"latitude",@"8.7", @"longitude",@"notes", @"deliver_terms_conditions",@"notes", @"notes", nil];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:stringURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {
     //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:nsdataFromBase64String name:@"ToyotaSupra" fileName:@"ToyotaSupra" mimeType:@"image/png"];

 }
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     imgRes=@"success";
     //here is place for code executed in success case
 }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
 {
     imgRes=@"fail";
     //here is place for code executed in error case
 }];
```

download the working code

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ot6kpiqs3pn2h0/AFNetwork.zip?dl=0

Comment: which version of afnetworking you used?

Comment: [manager POST:stringURL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) is deprecated from your code. i am trying with same code previous it's working fine. but after this deprecated warning. it's not working.