# Image upload using AFMultipartFormData AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-3

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some APi"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

UIImage *myImageObj = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"];
NSData *imageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageObj);

[manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                name:@"file"
                            fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    // etc.
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I am trying to upload image using afnetworking 3.0 but getting this error every time

> Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request
>   failed: internal server error (500)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: Some URL } { status
>   code: 500, headers {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
>       "Content-Length" = 291;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html";
>       Date = "Thu, 26 Jan 2017 11:41:19 GMT";
>       Server = "Werkzeug/0.11.11 Python/2.7.12"; } },

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245470/image-uploading-with-afnetworking-3-0?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

luckily postman provide objective-C and some other languages code but with AFNetworking i used this

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your URL"];

    UIImage *myImageObj = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageObj, 0.6);

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    //manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                    name:@"file"
                                fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        // etc.
    } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```