# Dealloc a viewcontroller warning

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I am getting this warning which is very annoying. Problem occurs when I tried to allocate new viewController from another viewController. Has anybody seen this warning before? What can I do to make it disappear? It important for me to fix it.

```
2016-09-19 16:55:09.216523 App[5204:1274804] [Common] _BSMachError: port e26f; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2016-09-19 16:55:09.217554 App[5204:1274804] [Common] _BSMachError: port e26f; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
```

Comment: Its already answered. Check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899586/error-message-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20

Comment: Did You solve it?

Answer (score 11):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
  // put your code to do allocate new viewController from 
  // another viewController here to ensure running in main thread
})
```