# Pass data between ViewControllers using dismiss

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have 3 ViewControllers A B C.
A and B ViewControllers use C to get data. Both A and B have a select button so if user is on A ViewController and presses select a segue is performed to C the user selects data that is stored in a dictionary pressed done and segue is performed to come back to A and dictionary is sent back using prepare for segue. Exactly the same if user is on B ViewController.

**Problems**
How do I let C know which ViewController to send the dictionary back to. 
Is their a way I can use dismiss to send the dictionary back to the ViewController the user came from or maybe a better way.

**Code from C ViewContrller**

```
@IBAction func doneBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToAddMeetingVC", sender: self)

    //Cant work cuz cant perform 2 segues at once
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToProjectVC", sender: <#T##Any?#>)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "backToAddMeetingVC" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! AddMeetingVC
        destination.selectedMembers = self.selectedMembers
    }

    if segue.identifier == "backToProjectVC" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ProjectsVC
        destination.selectedMembers = self.selectedMembers

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to implement a delegate. [Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40501780/1457385).

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625660/passing-data-between-2-uiviewcontroller-using-delegate-and-protocol. You will find your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C controller create

```
var dismissClosure: ((neededData) -> Void)?
```

In controller which presented C its controller(B) in prepareSegue need to declare  this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let controller = segue.destination as! C
    controller.dismissClosure = { [weak self] neededData in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        //TODO YOUR CHANGES
    }
}
```

When you dismiss or pop controller call this block in C controller

dismiss:

```
dismiss(true) {
   dismissClosure?(neededData)
}
```

pop

```
dismissClosure?(neededData)
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I solved that but now Im getting 2 new errors "Unable to insert COPY_SEND" and "Unable to deallocate send right" also the dismissClosure goes empty it is not picking up the neededData

Comment: Perhaps you are working with the UI not in the main thread 

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576314/dealloc-a-viewcontroller-warning). 

And of course in block use only weak self ref (I changed post)

Comment: Ok i don't understand your changes all Im trying to do is get dictionary from C to a Dictionary in B on dismissing C

Comment: In C controller create optional closure, 
in B controller in "prepare(for segue)" method declare this closure, because before appearing C controller called "prepare(for segue)" and initializate this closure
When you dismiss or pop C controller, call closure and put your dictionary in brackets.
The result from C will come to B Controller immediately, in B controller where you declare closure, and manipulate with your dictionary.

*VERY IMPORTANT*

in callback closure use weak self reference, not strong.
And when you make changes in UI like pop and dismiss make it in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `doneBtnPressed`either use below if you are not using `navigationController`

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

OR

use below line if you are using `navigationController`

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

prepare for segue looks fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable name like `mySelectedViewController` and sets its value whenever button action is performed, like when you click from `ViewController A` set  `mySelectedViewController = viewA` and then in `C ViewController` check `mySelectedViewController` value and work according to it.